# Flexbox Resize Event(?)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, flexbox

So I have a layout that heavily uses flexbox. I've been quite enjoying it, and it's great. As a note, I'm also heavily using AngularJS, and it's possible that my use of `ng-include` (or something else) might be contributing to the problem.

The problem is that I'm using a 3rd party component to draw a grid ([angular-grid](http://www.angulargrid.com/index.html) to be specific). It only resizes its columns when specifically called from JavaScript and can also be setup to do so once after initializing.

The problem here is that the columns aren't being resized correctly. They are seemingly resized to a different space. What I'm pretty certain is happening is that flexbox first draws the objects without accounting for flex, then after things are loaded, the layout stretches.

Assuming I'm correct in my assumption, I expected the solution to this would be finding a JavaScript (or JQuery or Angular) event to listen for when it's done resizing, then inform the grid that it needs to redraw the columns. That being said, I haven't found such an event, so maybe I'm approaching the problem wrong, or maybe I just haven't chosen the best search terms.

Just to help visualize the problem, here's an example HTML (the grid is a bit weird). (The style="..." is actually defined through css classes or Angular Material tags - see [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/layout/container).)

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
  <h1>Example Fixed Width Tag</h1>
  <div style="position: relative; flex: 1">
    <div ag-grid="definition" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">
    <!-- This is where the grid is drawn. -->
    <!-- The position: absolute is done because the grid requires the div here have -->
    <!-- a height and width property. -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can't really answer with a solution, but wanted to add another datapoint: I've run into similar issues with EmberJS while trying to resize a canvas to match the wrapping element. When elements were using flex, the resize wouldn't fit to the exact dimensions, but removing flex would immediately make it work.

Comment: if you set min-width: 1px; to the div with **flex: 1** does it work?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to know for sure when the browser finishes its repaint, so your options are limited to either doing some visibility tricks (hide the grid until you know all the data is there) or forcing redraw using a $timeout.

Answer (score 1):

If what you assume is the case, then there are 3 things you can try.

1) Add a `flex-basis` to your inner grid `div` so that it loads with the appropriate size right off the bat, avoiding the resize issue.

2) Apply the `display: flex` after initializing the ag-grid and adding the data to your state.

3) Redraw the ag-grid using `requestAnimationFrame` method once data is loaded and ag-grid initialized (this is probably the closest thing you're looking for in particular as far as waiting for borwser repainting to finish)